# center the drop down in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I made this CSS/HTML.

```css
    
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(151, 44, 44);
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  border-right:1px solid #f5b7b7;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5vh;
  width: 25%; /* Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(92, 25, 25);
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

/* ************************************************************** */

/* DROPDOWN */


.dropdown {
  float: left; 
  overflow: hidden;
  
}


.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1.5vh;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color:  rgb(92, 25, 25);
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar" id="tree">
        <a  href= "/">Home1</a> 
        <a  href= "/">Home2</a> 
        <a  href= "/">Home3</a> 
        
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" >&nbsp;TOPICS &nbsp; ▼&nbsp;</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">t1</a>
            <a href="#">t2</a>
            <a href="#">t3</a>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But there are 2 issues.

issue 1 -
Not able to center the drop down. using below code it centers but creates scroll bar on different resolutions and devices etc.

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left; 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(150%,0%)
}
```

issue 2 -
Drop down button is not expanded for entire of its 25% area (as are other buttons). ie.. Hovering is valid only over the text "TOPIC V"

Any ideas why its happening..not able to resolve since 2 days  ;[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first issue, use flexbox to align the items.

```css
.navbar {
  ...
  display: flex;
}
.dropdown {
  ...
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

For the second issue, you need to set the width to `100%`. Check the code snippet below for more details.

```css
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  ...
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
    
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(151, 44, 44);
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
  border-right:1px solid #f5b7b7;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5vh;
  width: 25%; /* Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(92, 25, 25);
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

/* ************************************************************** */

/* DROPDOWN */


.dropdown {
  float: left; 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}


.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1.5vh;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color:  rgb(92, 25, 25);
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar" id="tree">
        <a  href= "/">Home1</a> 
        <a  href= "/">Home2</a> 
        <a  href= "/">Home3</a> 
        
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" >&nbsp;TOPICS &nbsp; ▼&nbsp;</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">t1</a>
            <a href="#">t2</a>
            <a href="#">t3</a>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```